# Oracle get latest value based on parent/child partition

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table named "customer" that looks like this:

```
ID      ALPHA      BRAVO    CHARLIE          DATE
-------------------------------------------------
 1        111        222        333    02/02/2019
 2        333        444        555    11/11/2019
 3        666        555        777    12/12/2019
 4        777        888        999    05/05/2020
 5        100        101        110    12/25/2020
```

and I need to get the following output:

```
ID      ALPHA      BRAVO    CHARLIE          DATE     NEW_COL   ROW_NUM
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
 1        111        222        333    02/02/2019        333          4
 2        333        444        555    11/11/2019        333          3
 3        666        555        777    12/12/2019        333          2   
 4        777        888        999    05/05/2020        333          1
 5        100        101        110    12/25/2020        010          1
```

The ALPHA, BRAVO, and CHARLIE columns represent customer IDs. A given customer can have multiple IDs in the system. Records 1-4 represent IDs belonging to the same customer, let's say John. As per the table, John has 12 IDs, and his latest ID is 999. Record 5 represents another customer, let's say Jane. Jane has three IDs, and her last ID is 110.

The purpose of the ROW_NUM column is to get the last CUSTOMER.CHARLIE value. The idea is to use the first CHARLIE value as the partition. Basically, the goal is to get one parent:many children mapping. In this case, the ID 333 should be tied to 555, 777, and 999.

Here is the DDL/DML:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(ID NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
 ALPHA NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
 BRAVO NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
 CHARLIE NUMBER(20) NOT NULL,
 CREATEDDATE DATE
 );
 
INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES
(1, 111, 222, 333, to_date('02-FEB-19','DD-MON-RR'));

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES
(2, 333, 444, 555, to_date('11-NOV-19','DD-MON-RR'));

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES
(3, 666, 555, 777, to_date('12-DEC-19','DD-MON-RR'));

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES
(4, 777, 888, 999, to_date('05-MAY-20','DD-MON-RR'));

INSERT INTO CUSTOMER
VALUES
(5, 100, 101, 110, to_date('25-DEC-20','DD-MON-RR'));


COMMIT;
```

I have tried the following query, but it fails to populate the partition column correctly:

```
WITH
   charlies
   AS
      (SELECT DISTINCT charlie
       FROM customer),
   mult_customers
   AS
      (SELECT c.*, c.charlie AS NEW_COL
       FROM customer c
       UNION
       SELECT c.*,
              CASE WHEN c.alpha = e.charlie THEN c.alpha ELSE c.bravo END AS NEW_COL
       FROM customer c
            JOIN charlies e ON e.charlie = c.alpha OR e.charlie = c.bravo),
   ranked
   AS
      (SELECT mc.*,
              ROW_NUMBER ()
                 OVER (PARTITION BY NEW_COL ORDER BY createddate DESC) AS row_num
       FROM mult_customers mc)
SELECT *
FROM ranked
ORDER BY ID;
```

Thanks for any help provided.

Comment: How many rows in your real table? Is this task for production use or just student home work?

Comment: this task is for production use; the real table contains about 8,000 records right now, but over time, the record count will continue to grow. Within the next year it may have 100,000 records.

Answer (score 3):

You task is known as connected components. I wrote about 7-8 years ago solution for this and even pl/sql package: http://orasql.org/2017/09/29/connected-components/

This PL/SQL solution is much more effective then pure SQL solutions: http://orasql.org/2014/02/28/straight-sql-vs-sql-and-plsql/

Let me know if you need help with adopting it for your task.

Comment: Thanks for sharing Sayan! Your solution has come in handy.